# Which headers do i need to set in my REST-API response to get my simple Ionic 3 WebApp GET request working?

Tags: angular, go, ionic-framework

I'm stuck in creating my first Ionic app.

### Scenario:

1. Created a simple REST-API with Golang. It's working fine when i make the GET call in browser and / or Postman. The Output is:

   ```
   [
       {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Leanne Graham"
       },
       {
           "id": 100,
           "name": "I COME FROM YOUR OWN REST-API!!!"
       }
   ]
   ```
2. I created a simple Ionic 3 (with Angular 5) web app based on some tutorials. I just wanted to diplay my test data in an ionic-list with ngFor. This is working fine with some static (hard-coded) data.
3. I then switched from hard-coded data to a REST-API. The tutorial suggested me to use `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`. This also worked fine; I was able to display the users' data (tried only with `id` and `name`) in my ionic-list.
4. I then switched to my own REST-API. I took similar (a little less) JSON content like the one from `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`. See above.

### Problem:

My ionic-list stays empty after fetching data from my own REST-API but works with any other public API.

### Thoughts:

- Since the content of my REST-API response is nearly the same as the one from `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` i guess there is something wrong in my api-response headers. No tutorial covers the header stuff. This is why I didn't set them. I tried different headers in my response like `w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")` but this doesn't help.
- Are there general headers I always have to set when responding to a GET request from an Ionic app?
- When helpful I naturally will post my app's code here.

Comment: Is your frontend served by the Go server? If not you will have to set [cross-origin headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If this is the problem your browser will also complain loudly in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Enable cross origin on Go code, Or else Add it `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` in to your header

Comment: @Peter My REST-API is standalone. The Ionic app is served with Ionic serve.

Comment: @VeluDhanesh This worked! I love you :) Thanks for sharing your knowledge!